# Distribution of sum of geometrically scaled uniform variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_k$ ($k=1,2 \cdots$) be iid uniform random variables in $[-1,1]$. Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a^k \,X_k$ for some fixed $0<a<1$.

Which is the density of $S= \lim_{n\to \infty}S_{n}$? Clearly, it's limited to $[-\frac{1}{1-a},\frac{1}{1-a}]$, and it should be continuous (I'm not sure if differentiable?) Does it correspond to a well known distribution?

(Notice that $S$ corresponds to a $AR(1)$ -autoregressive process- where the input noise is uniform. It's also a typical example of an infinite sum of independent r.v. where the CLT does not hold)

Answer (score 1):

We may express the characteristic function of $S$ as following. $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale, so it converges a.s. to $S$. Indeed, $\sup_nE[|S_n|^2]=\sup_nV[S_n]\propto\sum_n a^{2n}<\infty$ so it is uniformly integrable. We get
$$E[e^{i\xi S_n}]=\prod_{1\leq k \leq n}E[e^{i(\xi a^k)X_k}]=\prod_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{e^{i\xi a^k}-e^{-i\xi a^k}}{2i\xi a^k}=\prod_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{\sin(\xi a^k)}{\xi a^k}$$
So by dominated convergence $E[e^{i\xi S}]=\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{\sin(\xi a^n)}{\xi a^n}$.

Comment: Thanks. This is of course true, but it's rather formal, it not does not say much about the density.

Comment: @leonbloy: this tells you: (1) this may not be a well known distribution (I'm not aware of this CF characterising anything in closed form), (2) heuristically, numerically inverting the CF for very large $n$ gives you the (rather continuous) shape of what could be the candidate for its density