# Understanding an Answer to a Math StackExchange Post : Convergence of a Summed Sequence

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

Previously, I had posted a question here in which I was interested in learning about the mathematical conditions (e.g. iid) required for the Central Limit Thereon to be valid: [Central Limit Theorem without IID?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670833/central-limit-theorem-without-iid) . Specifically, I was interested in deliberately creating a counter-example in which these conditions were not met, and forcefully showing that in the absence of these conditions, the results of the Central Limit Theorem do not hold.

In this question, I was provided with an answer where such a counter-example was outlined:

**An example for independent but not identically distributed (from [Distribution of sum of geometrically scaled uniform variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597485/distribution-of-sum-of-geometrically-scaled-uniform-variables)). Let $Z_k$ be iid Uniform on $[-1,1]$ and let $X_k = a^k Z_k $ for some $0<a<1$. In this case, $X_k$ are independent, uniform on $[-a^k,a^k]$, so that $E[X_k]=0$ and $\sigma_k^2= \frac13 a^{-2k}$. Because $\sum X_k$ is limited to the range $(−1/(1−a),1/(1-a))$, the sum cannot converge to a Gaussian distribution.**

I spent some time trying to go over the logic in this answer, but I can't seem to figure out why this counter-example the sequence $X_k$ DOES NOT converge to a Gaussian distribution (i.e. the main result of the Central Limit Theorem).

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!

Citation: @MISC {4670851,
TITLE = {Central Limit Theorem without IID?},
AUTHOR = {leonbloy (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/312/leonbloy)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4670851 (version: 2023-04-10)},
EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4670851},
URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4670851}
}

Comment: As said in the answer, for any integer $N$, we have almost surely that $Z_N := \sum_{1\le k\le N}  X_k \in (−1/(1−a),1/(1-a))$ almost surely. Therefore for all $t\le −1/(1−a)$ (say),
$$\mathbb P(Z_N \le t) = 0 $$
In particular, since for any Gaussian random variable $Z$, we have $\mathbb P(Z \le t) > 0 $, this implies that there exists no Gaussian $Z$ such that
$$\mathbb P(Z_N \le t) \to \mathbb P(Z\le t)$$